# Gosu for loop through rows for a single column for date check

Tags: gosu, guidewire

Currently,

I have a roadblock in Gosu.

I created an entity(table) that has the last batch run date, Right now, my current code checks the employee data in Guidewire database tables and inserts into our integration database which is SQLserver.

If and when the system is down am currently persisting the last run date of batch run in the entity I created.

Now for example if the application is down for 3 days due to some issues and back up after that I should be able to send an email on employee data for last 3 days each in different email.

I will have to  find the difference of the last run date(which is in entity) and current system date, then loop through each date until it reaches current date and trigger batch job and send out emails.

Most of the coding is done except for the looping.

any sample code is appreciated.

Comment: Missing implementation is not a valid question. Could you please state a valid question? Also if you would share some code (just enough - more in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) that would help to get you sorted fast.

Comment: Where is the code? Your question is ongoing.